# 英語が残っている:質問の作成ページ[share your knowlledge, Q&A-style]

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 日本語

質問を作成するページで
share your knowledge, Q&A-style

という英語が残っています。

[image: 未翻訳部分]

これを

"Q&A形式にして、あなたの知識を共有しましょう!"
などとしてはいかがでしょうか

Answer (score 1):

「Q&A形式にして、あなたの知識を共有しましょう!」を適用しました。リンク先がまだ英語ですが、とりあえずリンク文書が日本語になります（次回のビルドから）